How to create a categorical column based on two dates in Python
I have the following data:
# importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# create data table
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/7/2020 19:09','11/18/2019 20:23','5/19/2023 14:55','9/11/2019 17:14']}) 

I would like to create a categorical variable term_type based on two dates in Python, using the following definition \



Term Type
Range




Summer
Mar 23 - Jul 6


Fall
Jul 7 - Oct 23


Spring
Oct 24 - Mar 22



MY ATTEMPT 
I tried to use np.where to create this column using conditions. I first extracted the month and day into month & day columns, respectively. Please see below:
# extracting month and day
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format= date_format).dt.month
df['day']  = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format= date_format).dt.day

# use np.where to create a conditional column
df['term_type'] = np.where((df['month']>=3) & (df['month']<6) & (df['day']<=6) & (df['day']>=23),'summer',
                    np.where((df['month']>=10) & (df['month']<=3) & (df['day']>=22),'spring','fall'))

But the output is not what I expected. It all turns out to be "Fall" for all of them.

This is my desired output.
# Desired output
df['desired_term_type'] = ['spring','spring','summer','fall']


Can someone please help me explain what I did wrong with my code, and how can I fix this problem? Any help is appreciated!

For a fast/vectorized approach, you could use a custom encoding, for example multiplying the month by 100 and adding the day, then passing to cut:
# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# encode date
s = df['date'].dt.month.mul(100)+df['date'].dt.day

df['term_type'] = pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 323, 707, 1024, np.inf],
                         labels=['spring', 'summer', 'fall'],
                         ordered=False)

Output:
                 date term_type
0 2020-01-07 19:09:00    spring
1 2019-11-18 20:23:00    spring
2 2023-05-19 14:55:00    summer
3 2019-09-11 17:14:00      fall

To encode the reference dates:
ref = pd.to_datetime(['03-23', '07-07', '10-24'], format='%m-%d')
ref.month*100+ref.day
# Index([323, 707, 1024], dtype='int32')

alternative
You could also force the year to 2000 and use the dates of this year a references:
df['term_type'] = pd.cut(
    pd.to_datetime(df['date']).add(pd.DateOffset(year=2000)),
    bins=pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01', '2000-03-23', '2000-07-07', '2000-10-24', '2001-01-01']),
    labels=['spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'spring'],
    ordered=False)

Note that adding DateOffset is not vectorized.

Thank you so much for your approach. It works out. I really appreciate it.

The conditions in np.where are wrong: you're not considering dates for months that lie between the start and end month.
Here's one way to achieve what you want:
df["term_type"] = np.where(
    # Mar 23 - Jul 6
    (df["month"] == 3) & (df["day"] >= 23)
    | (df["month"] == 7) & (df["day"] <= 6)
    | df["month"].between(4, 6),
    "summer",
    # Jul 7 - Oct 23
    np.where(
        (df["month"] == 7) & (df["day"] >= 7)
        | (df["month"] == 10) & (df["day"] <= 23)
        | df["month"].between(8, 9),
        "fall",
        "spring",
    ),
)

Output:
                 date  month  day term_type
0 2020-01-07 19:09:00      1    7    spring
1 2019-11-18 20:23:00     11   18    spring
2 2023-05-19 14:55:00      5   19    summer
3 2019-09-11 17:14:00      9   11      fall

